# Sync problems developing React projects on OneDrive

Tags: reactjs, onedrive

I made a React project using npx create-react-app inside my OneDrive folder on Windows 10.

OneDrive complained about one of the folders being named '~' (it was a folder with Node config files made automatically by create-react-app).

This was honestly a huge nightmare:

- I could not rename, move or delete the folder myself. Windows Explorer didn't allow it because there was a 'sync error'
- OneDrive would just completly stop syncing until the issue is fixed. I could not do anything manually, so my only option was to use their 'rename' button in the error message (which is supposed to automatically rename the file and fix the error). This did not work. I would try again and again over the span of a few days and it would do nothing, the error persisted.
- Ultimately I copied my project outside OneDrive, but now I wasn't able to delete my old folders. I tried everything I could think of: pause sync, try to delete them with Windows in Safe Mode, uninstalled OneDrive in the end. I managed to delete most of the contents (with a lot of effort), but there were stil some Node directories that would not be deleted. I was getting a 'reparse point buffer' error which I solved by running chkdsk /f /x

Partly, I'm posting this hoping that my experience would help someone that has simmilar issues with OneDrive, but I also want to know how to keep React projects in my OneDrive.

I like having everything on my laptop in my OneDrive folder so it is synced: I want to be able continue my work when I move to my computer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same problem.  I figured out if I moved the react folder into another folder and then deleted the other folder that worked try it.  My onedrive still kept trying to sync something for a while but it finally quit and now everything is okay.  That is until I do another react project and onedrive will be messed up again for sure.

After deleting the folder press <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and run this command to reset onedrive

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe /reset
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I remember trying something similar with little succes at that time. For some reason I had issues resteting onedrive.exe
I moved my React projects outside OneDrive since, and I rely on GitHub for syncing needs. This kind of issues makes OneDrive very frustraiting to use, and it's dissapointing from a company as big as Microsoft.